# arrays/lists and their dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I have a problem analysing the following code:

```
 for (int argI = 1; argI < args_.size(); ++argI) //size(): Return the number of 
 {                                       //arguments.
      argListString += ' ';         //Space into string
      argListString += args_[argI]; //new argument into string

      if (args_[argI][0] == '-')    // ????
      {
           const char *optionName = &args_[argI][1];   //????
```

My problem are the lines marked with `????`. When I look up the object `args_` it ist of type `stringList` and `stringList` is templateclass of `List<T>`. `List<T>` ist defined as

```
Template<class T> 
class Foam::List< T > 
A 1D array of objects of type <T>, where the size of the vector is known and used for subscript bounds checking, etc. Storage is allocated on free-store during
construction.
```

So if `args_` is a 1D array why is it accessed like a 2D array in line 415 and 417?

greetings
streight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an vector/list of strings. Strings are a sequence of chars. Thus the **index operator**( [] ) will likely provide access to the single chars of the string.

*415* therefor checks the first char of the string and *417* accesses the substring from the second char to the end.

Comment: Ok, just one more question: With the operator & in line 417 I generally should get the adress of a object. So, do I get here the adress of the second char?

Comment: It returns the address of the second char. A c string is basically an array of chars (multiply chars in a row with a NULL-char at the end ('\0')). Therefor a c string `char* foo` is nothing more than a pointer to one element of this array. Thus you can always add an offset (e.g `foo + 4`) to acquire a substring (because your just moving forward in that sequence of chars). Im not quite sure, how they retain the original relation to the c string in the [] operator here, but my guess is, that they return a `const char &`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `args_[argI]` is a string type, and the string type overloads `[]` to access the characters within the string.

So this looks for options of the form `-flibble`; the first marked line checks whether the argument begins with `-`, and the second sets `optionName` to point to `flibble`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a one-dimensional vector `args_` where each element is of type `T`. Now, it would seem that this type `T` is a string (either a string type or a pointer to a C-style string) the elements of which can be accessed using the index operator [].

As such, it is not actually "accessed like a 2D array". Instead, each item is accessed as a one-dimensional array and the resulting object is in turned indexed.

So, assuming `T` is `char*` (which makes sense for text strings), this would make `args_[argI]` an element of type `char*` which is a pointer to a string. This string is then indexed as an array, so that `args_[argsI][1]` refers to the second character in the `argI`th string in the vector called `args_`.